# Embedding of a boundary component induces isomorphism on homologies

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cobordism

> Let $(A,\partial)$ be a surface with boundary. Pick a relative bordism $W$ from $A$ to itself, i.e. $\partial W \cong (A\cup_{\partial}-A)$. Is it true that inclusion $i:A\hookrightarrow W$ induces isomorphism on homology groups ?

I am reading an article about the special case of my question where author says: "Mayer-Vietoris sequence argument shows this relative bordism is a homology bordism". I do not quite get it. I know that bordism groups $\Omega_k(-)$ define an extraordinary homology theory so Mayer-Vietoris sequence holds. But I do not see how it can be used.

P.S. Assume everything is path-connected.

Replying to the comments below:
The original question comes from the example of $X_f$ here [Higher homotopy groups of a string complement in a cylinder.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706031/higher-homotopy-groups-of-a-string-complement-in-a-cylinder). So I would also accept an answer which assumes that the genus of $A$ is $0$ or more simply the bordism is given by $X_f$.

Comment: Isn’t a torus with two open disks removed a counterexample?

Comment: @ConnorMalin I am looking for examples with one dimension higher.

Comment: It will be neither injective nor surjective in general. I thought no you are missing some extra assumptions.

Comment: Perhaps you should see if he has a definition of relative bordism in his article.

Comment: @ConnorMalin relative the boundary which I included in the question

Comment: @MoisheKohan do you think the assumptions on the dimensions are not enough? Anyway, I will add some more assumptions in the question. Maybe it will be more helpful.

Comment: No, it is still wrong: Even if you take $A=D^2$, you do not get surjectivity, even if $A$ is an annulus, you do not get injectivity.

Comment: @MoisheKohan if I take $A=D^2$, then can $W$ be different then $D^3$? Note that boundary of $W$ is not a disjoint union of $D^2$ but a union along $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: Yes, of course: Take you favorite closed 3-manifold (say, $T^3$) and remove an open ball from it. You get a compact manifold whose boundary is $S^2$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan indeed.. Thank you!